# How can I obtain increasing series of name of variable using a DO-LOOP?

Tags: sas, do-loops

I would like to obtain something like this:

```
variable_1
variable_2
variable_3
variable_4
```

from a DO-LOOP in SAS, in order to use these variables inside the same macro. How can I do it?

Comment: Where do you want to obtain that? In a data step?

Comment: Yes in a macro for a data step

Comment: Why not just use a variable list? `variable_1-variable_4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This macro creates a liste variable1-variable4.

```
%macro m;
%do i = 1 %to 4;
variable_&i.
%end;
%mend;

%put %m;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might not need macro at all if you use a variable based array.

```
data want;
  set have;

  array vars variable_1-variable_4;

  do index = 1 to dim(vars);
    ... vars(index) ...   /* access ith arrayed variable */
  end;

/* more code */
run;
```